# AG Grid filter: suppress blank/null value

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Is there a way to prevent displaying "Blank" in the filter options?
Something like:

```
let columnDefs = [{
    {
      field: 'name',
      filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
      filterParams: {
        suppressSelectBlank : true
      }
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok you are looking for `filterParams.values` this will filter out blanks programmatically.

```
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      headerName: 'Set filter column',
      field: 'value',
      flex: 1,
      filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
      filterParams: {
        values: (params: SetFilterValuesFuncParams) => {
            const list = params.context.rowData.map((x) => x.value);
            const unique: any = [...Array.from(new Set(list))];
            const noBlanks = unique.filter(x => x);
            params.success(noBlanks);
        },
      },
    },
  ];
```

[working demo (plunkr)](https://plnkr.co/edit/S75PFKa56imNV0iT?open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

additional:

[example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-set-filter-list/#synchronous-values)

[docs](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/filter-set/#reference-ISetFilterParams-values)